# how to manage the inactive or soft-deleted records in the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was doing my research about the advantages and disadvantages of inactive a row or in different word the soft-delete. I found a big argument in both sides. However, I've decided to use this technique in my database design.

I've stopped with a question "How should I deal with the relational data linked by FK?".

Update case to inactive.

When I update some Ids in 'T2'  do I need to  update the relational data to inactive in 'T3'?

so How about if the update will affect the a row in 'T1' and the database is more complex?

How is it going be the data management in regard to soft-deleted records?

Option 1

should I manage it by updating all relational data?

OR

Option 2

should I manage it in select query?

'option 1' would need a very expensive query?

It's a kind of maze that needs to be resolved with depth first search.
[image]

Thanks a lot for your helps. I hope my question is useful that reaches the certain level of question quality.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Why should you "update the relational data to inactive in 'T3'" when you "update some Ids in 'T2'"? What are these two operations anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay, and sorry if my question it is not clear enough, my English is not my first language. Anyway, I wish to be clear to the point,
should I do double operations to inactive the relational data or I should just manage it in the select statement?

Comment: This doesn't help me to understand and be able to help you ...

Comment: sorry to know that, but which part of the question you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Lets assume you have these tables: order, orderitem, product. When an order is deleted, it gets the deleted flag and stays in the database. All orderitems are therefore also deleted, but products of course are not. Your business logic needs to be aware of the relation between the objects.

Now it depends on what you want to do when an order item is deleted. It doesn't necessarily need to be soft-deleted. Only the order is. If you still want to soft-delete the items, you have to add an deleted flag to it as well.

When the product is deleted, you have to make sure that there is no active order item referencing it. Again, it depends on how you want to handle this case. You usually want to block it.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would have gone with Option 2. Think about the frequency at which you need to delete a record in a table as compared to frequency at which you need to read a record. Definitely Read frequency must be more.
This can easily be managed in SELECT queries by using some WHERE clauses.
This technique is also very handy when it comes to writing linq-to-sql or EF codes in c#.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are in compliance with Second normal form (2NF), then if you mark a record in T2 as inactive (or soft-deleted) then there is no need to mark the child records in T3 as inactive.  in accordance to 2NF, the inactive attribute in T2 only applies to T2, not to T3.

Comment: Personally, I always use T-SQL instead of EF and Linq-to-sql. I think that would my new search title. In regards to the load balance. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion.